# "He eyeballed me pensively"; using bodyparts as verbs

Tags: word-choice, etymology, verbs, terminology

What are these words called, and why are they used in place of traditional verbs? For example:

> - She handed me a pencil. [*handed* instead of *gave*]
> - He eyeballed me pensively. [*eyeballed* instead of *leered* or *looked at*]
> - She eyed the carrots. [*eyed* instead of *looked at*]
> - He mouthed some words to me. [*mouthed* instead of *spoke/said*]

There's so many more, so these are just a few examples. This is colloquial speech, but it kind of irks me when I hear people say body parts in place of verbs (excl. *handed* because it's so common). Is there a particular name for this usage? Is this done in other languages?

Comment: They are zero-derived uses of English nouns as verbs. It's too bad it irks you, because it's perfectly normal. There's nothing sacred about body-part nouns in English.

Comment: You asked about other languages. The French do not make as much use  as we do of body parts as verbs. You can't 'eye' someone, or 'hand something' to someone, though some of their verbs do employ mention of the body. For example 'She threw him a glance' would be 'Elle lui jeta un coup d'oeil' literally 'she threw him a blow of her eye'

Comment: And to be accurate, "mouthing" words is not the same as speaking words.  "Mouthing" usually means moving one's mouth as if speaking but without making a sound.  "Mouthing off", however, does mean speaking impolitely to someone. :-)

Comment: ***elbow** someone aside, **head** the ball, **finger** the criminals (or girlfriend), **stomach** arguments, **leg it**, **nose out** the truth, **toe** the line,* etc., etc. Why would these perfectly normal usages "irk" anyone?

Comment: I don't know if John Lawler would agree with me, but English is essentially a language of vocabulary. Exquisite speakers of English are always playing with words and word-forms. My only other real experience is with French, and there people often attempt feats of grammar, with exquisite subjunctive forms etc. But French has a far smaller vocabulary than English. And French speakers do not appear to have the same licence to create words on the way we do. Hence words like 'eyeballed' have come into being.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I get irked if I'm bollocked?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm pretty sure its __tow__ **the line**, similar to how a tow truck __tows__ vehicles. But yes, those just irk me the wrong way.

Comment: @riista: Nah - someone [asked that long ago on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/45906/2637), and it was closed as GR.

Comment: @WS2: Careful! One of the mods might [brain](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/brain+someone) you if you keep referring to inappropriate body parts!

Comment: I don't know why you deem these "colloquial," and their alternatives "traditional." How long does a verb need to be a verb before it becomes "traditional?" The OED cites 14th-century instances of _eye_ being used as a verb; _hand_ meaning "to give something to someone" reaches back to at least the 1600s; _mouth(e)_ as a verb traces back 200 years before that. These verbs are just about as old as the language itself – but you might've learned that on your own, had you managed to foot it to your local library. ;^) _I am tyr'd Sir, And nere shall foot it home_ (1637).

Comment: If I had your username, @FumbleFingers , I'd be careful about alerting the mods.

Comment: @FumbleFingers They haven't the guts!

Comment: @WS2: I'm **gutted** that you're not playing the game! We're supposed to be *verbifying*, not just finding figurative usages of nouns that remain nouns.

Comment: So it irks you when people say it, but it doesn't irk you if *even more* people say it? I'm not sure I'm quite following this logic...

Comment: Definitely don't start on the noun list because the knee-jerk reaction would be to head down a hairy path!

Comment: Yh that is a bit *lowbrow* , you've got some *cheek* ! I hope the moderators don't get too *nosey* and *muscle* us out. It's all a bit *tongue-in-cheek* ! ;)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Enough of this arsing around I'm off to watch the ten o'clock news.

Comment: @WS2: Several things I wouldn't agree with. English, like Mandarin, is an analytic language, and therefore it's the **syntax**, not the vocabulary, that forms the grammar. Every language has vocabulary; it's a big job learning words and idioms anywhere. Also, French does not have "a far smaller vocabulary than English". Once the size gets beyond what any native speaker needs to know -- roughly 10-20,000 words and a hundred times that many idioms to use them in -- they're all the same size.

Comment: Keep your hair on.

Comment: I didn't think eyeballing was something that you could do "pensively". That sounds weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One at a time:

- She handed me a pencil. [handed instead of gave]

  *Handed* and *gave* are not synonymous.  *Handed* is far more specific, when used in a literal sense (as in your example), as it suggests the action of giving is performed by way of the hand.  "She handed me a pencil" elicits a vision of a woman reaching forward her hand, gripping a pencil, as I take it.  If one says instead "She gave me a pencil," it could just as well elicit a setting around a Christmas tree, in which I untie a bow, rip the paper, open a box, and find a beautifully decorated Christmas... pencil!
- He eyeballed me pensively. [eyeballed instead of leered or looked at]

  *Eyeball* is also more specific than *looked at*, and has different connotations than *leer*.  According to [dictionry.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eyeball?s=ts):

  > Informal. to look at, check, or observe closely: two opponents eyeballing each other.

  One could say "He looked closely at me," and you would get across a very similar meaning.  But again, the visions elicited by the phrases are, at least for me, quite different. To me, *eyeballed* is much more colorful, perhaps even poetic.  If that's not your style, don't use the word.
- She eyed the carrots. [eyed instead of looked at]

  The verb *Eye* is, once again, far more specific than *look at*.  It indicates a more intensive, intentional action, than simply "looking."
- He mouthed some words to me. [mouthed instead of spoke/said]

  This is the most obvious case where the two words are not synonymous.  In fact, they're almost antonyms!  To *say* or *speak* means you make verbal communication. To *mouth* the words means you do *not* make any verbal communication!

---

Now, generally speaking, why do we use body parts as verbs in English?  I think others have said it well in comments, but it boils down to creativity, colorful language and, because we can.

Answer (score 4):

> **She gave me a pencil.** vs. **She handed me a pencil.**

*She gave me a pencil* could mean she gave me pencil as a Christmas gift. Or it could mean she left a spare pencil in my locker. On the other hand, *she handed me the pencil* indicates that we were face-to-face at the time of the transaction, and she put it in my hand. In other words, *handed* is more specific and descriptive.

> **She looked at the carrots.** vs. **She eyed the carrots.**

I don't see these as equivalent, either. NOAD defines *eyed* as:

> **eye** (*v.*) to look at ***with interest*** [emphasis added]

*She eyed the carrots*, then, is more vivid than *she looked at the carrots*. Perhaps she was walking through the farmer's market, and the carrots were a brilliant orange, in peak season, looking scrumptious enough to make her mouth water. If that were the case, *she looked at the carrots* would be a rather bland way to describe her fervency.

I supposed you could have picked alternate wordings to describe her actions and get around this problem:

> **She placed a pencil in my hand, and then ogled the carrots.**

However, much like the commenters to your question, I'm at a loss to figure out why this body-part-as-verb phenomenon "irks" you. Moreover, as I mentioned in my comment, these verbs are centuries old; it's not like they represent some newfangled way of expressing something. And even when a body part is rarely used as a verb, I'm glad we have a language that is flexible enough to let it be used as one:

> *Orr's best remembered moment, of course, came when he [**wristed**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CySsevIk7lg) a Stanley Cup winning shot past Glenn Hall of St. Louis, then sailed gleefully through the air*...<sup>[1](http://www.thecrimson.com/article/1979/1/12/orr-ending-at-the-beginning-pboston/)</sup>

[image]

It seems like if there would be any reason to be irked, it would be the other way around:

> *Sorry, you can't use that as a verb. It's a body part.*

Now *that* would be vexing – and hard to enforce. I wouldn't want to be shouldered with that duty!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a form of [metonymy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) to me, although all the examples of metonyms I've seen are nouns.